# How to get all data from from a view (which is in schema 1 with out VPD policy) when ran from schema 2 with VPD policy?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I have two schema, one with policy and another with out policy. I created a view to select all data from the schema 1 which do not have policy and gave select grants to schema 2. Now when i run the view in schema 2, I do not get all data.  But I want all data when i run the query from schema 2.

```
select * from schema1.view_name
```

When ran in schema 1 i get all data. Then, I gave select grants to run the view in schema 2

```
select * from schema1.view_name
```

When ran in schema 2, I do not get any data.